# how to insert jtable only one column data into DB mysql?

Tags: java

I need to insert only one column data from jtable to DB mysql,I found a way to do it but i'm facing a problem which occur when i inserted less data than expected eg: insert 2 rows instead of 3 rows; `Error:java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception 2>=2`

How do I get rid of this ?

You can check out my code down ...Thanks

```
try
        {
            //String product3 = "null";
           int rows = jTable1.getRowCount();
           int cols = jTable1.getColumnCount();
           String salesql = "insert into salling(orderid,saledate,prod1,prod2,prod3,tax,subtotal,total) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
           pst = conn.prepareStatement(salesql);
           pst.setString(1, jTextFieldOrderNo.getText());
           pst.setString(2, jTextFieldDate.getText());

           for(int row =0; row <= rows; row++)
           {
               String product1 = (String)jTable1.getValueAt(0, 0);
               String product2 = (String)jTable1.getValueAt(1, 0);
               String product3 = (String)jTable1.getValueAt(2, 0);
              // String product3 = (String)jTable1
               pst.setString(3, product1);
               pst.setString(4, product2);
               pst.setString(5, product3);
           }
          pst.setString(6, jTextFieldTax.getText());
          pst.setString(7, jTextFieldSuTotal.getText()); 
          pst.setString(8, jTextFieldTotal.getText()); 

          pst.execute();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data saved...");


        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you want to insert values into one column only, what are all those pst.setString() methods for? And your insert statement - you're inserting into 8 columns, not 1.

Comment: @Pavel pointed the right thing

Comment: No I want to take data from jtable (only one column from this jtable) to insert them into different columns in DB mysql